# Copy the pdf file from the latest folder in any specific pattern

Tags: batch-file

I created a .bat that will copy pdf file in specified server. The folder structure of file is like this :

```
\\server\
 '----010000-0000\
      '----010000-0000-0705-1\
            '-------010000-0000-DATA.pdf
      '----010000-0000-0705-2\
            '-------010000-0000-DATA.pdf
```

`010000-0000` is the code that the user will input. Then batch will search with the exact folder with the code as filename and must copy the pdf file..

My problem is the folder before the pdf file is always has a 4 random numbers which is `0705` (as an example). What I was thinking is to pass through that folder what ever the 4 random numbers value will be. To copy the pdf file

for example (if would do a static code, it will be like this) :

```
set /p code=Input Control Number:
goto FILE

:FILE
set VER=0

:FILE1
set /a VER +=1
if exist "%fp%\%CODE%\%CODE%-0705-%VER%\%CODE%-DATA.pdf" goto FPCOPY
IF NOT EXIST ELSE GOTO FILE1

:FPCOPY
xcopy "%fp%\%CODE%\%CODE%-0705-%VER%\%CODE%-DATA.pdf" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Backup\%CODE%\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H
start "" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Backup\%code%"
```

It will surely copy the data. But as I said that 4 digit numbers is always random.

What I have tried is this one (I only replace the 4 digit no. by an *) :

```
set /p code=Input Control Number:
goto FILE

:FILE
set VER=0

:FILE1
set /a VER +=1
if exist "%fp%\%CODE%\%CODE%-*-%VER%\%CODE%-DATA.pdf" goto FPCOPY
IF NOT EXIST ELSE GOTO FILE1

:FPCOPY
xcopy "%fp%\%CODE%\%CODE%-*-%VER%\%CODE%-DATA.pdf" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Backup\%CODE%\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H
start "" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Backup\%code%"
```

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve]. Where is `CODE` defined?

Comment: @jwdonahue set /p code=Input Code Number: .. the user will only input the code, then the batch will look for its folder..

Comment: Your pattern appears to be something like ??????-????-????-?.

Comment: @jwdonahue yes..

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish?  If you had read [ask], we wouldn't have to play 20 questions.  I think we have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  If you want to ignore 1705, don't look at or think about it.  How hard can that be?  What is your script supposed to do?

Comment: Using my telepathy, I have determined that you should read `help robobopy`, specifically, the `-XD` option.  You probably want `-XD *-1705-*`.

Comment: [Edit] your title/post to say what you are trying to accomplish.  Not what you think you need to do to accomplish it.

Comment: You want to copy directories that match a pattern, while excluding a sub-pattern.

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm sorry for being noob here.. And yes thats what i want..I want to pass through the folder regardless what is '1705' value will be.. to copy the pdf data inside...

Comment: So are you simply trying to copy the `pdf` file from the latest folder in any specific pattern? If you can edit your question and show an example of what you want to copy and what not, then it would help not having to ask you numerous questions.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard see my edit......ty

Comment: @jwdonahue see my edit in my question..

Comment: @GerhardBarnard It doesn't work...

Comment: ok, give me a few minutes, will post an answer for you now. one question though. if a file exists in version `1` and `2` do you want to overwrite the file?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard oh i forgot. It must get the latest data. So it will get the pdf file in version 2... so it will be VER=10 then set /a VER -=1 ..

Comment: Ok. Give me a few minute. Will post an answer from my laptop.

Comment: can a older version directory be created when a newer directory exists? for instance can `??????-????-????-01` be created after `??????-????-????-02`?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard No sir..if in version 2 there is a match pdf file... then it will not go to version 1..

Comment: I am referring more to when folders are created. will version 2 folder always be newer than version 1 folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming the later versioned directories are always created after the previous versions:

```
@echo off
set fp=<SET YOUR FILEPATH HERE>
set /p "code=Input Control Number: "
set cnt=0
    :start
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad /o-d "%fp%\%code%" ^| findstr "%code%" ^|more +%cnt%') do (
       if exist "%%~a\%code%-DATA.pdf" (
           set "found=%%~a"
           goto :done
    ) else (
     if %cnt% equ 10 goto :eof
     set /a cnt+=1
     goto start
 )
)
    :done
    set cnt=
    xcopy "%found%\%code%-DATA.pdf" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%code%\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H
    start "" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%code%"
```

We really just check the latest folder for the file, if it does not exist, we skip that folder and try and older version until we find it, then copy the file.

Comment: Just one more thing. What if loop doesn't find any existing folder? how can I terminate it?

Comment: Well that is easy we can set a limit on the version. I will update the answer with a limit of 10. You can just adjust it.